# Using not equal operator in Cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have find query that looks like this.

```
$this->paginate('Article', array('Article.status !=' => 'Inactive', 'Article.user_id !=' => $blocked_ids, 'Article.tags LIKE' => "%" . trim($this->params['url']['tag']) . "%"))
```

where $blocked_ids is an array of ids. It throws an error

```
SQL Error: 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= ('170')
```

When I removed `!=` it works fine. No Errors

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As @Josh suggested, try using NOT IN. The correct format for CakePHP 1.3.x is:

```
$this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'NOT' => array(
            'User.id' => array(1, 2, 3)
        )
    )
));
```

Taken from http://cakebaker.42dh.com/2007/04/26/how-to-use-not-in-in-a-condition/

Answer (score 11):

```
$this->paginate(
                'Article',
                array (
                     'Article.status <>' => 'Inactive', 
                     'Article.user_id !=' => $blocked_ids, 
                     'Article.tags LIKE' => "%" . trim($this->params['url']['tag']) . "%"
                   )
              );
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be handled when you're getting your data in your model function.  You should exclude them by using code like this:

```
'conditions' => array(
     'Article.status' => 'active',
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NOT IN` instead [[MySQL Reference]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_not-in):

```
$this->paginate('Article', array('Article.status !=' => 'Inactive', 'Article.user_id NOT IN' => $blocked_ids, 'Article.tags LIKE' => "%" . trim($this->params['url']['tag']) . "%"))
```